# InteractionCollector is is not being set properly in Quick.DB .sqlite file discord.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js, quick.db

I'm trying to use quick.db for an InteractionCollector manager in discord.js with typescript, and since there can't be more than 1 collector active, whenever a user uses a command that has a collector, it gets set into a map with the user id, and whenever the user uses another command with a collector, the old one gets destroyed.
The problem is, if I use a normal JavaScript map, it works, but since it is heavier I want to use a .sqlite file with quick.db, and when I set the collector, it does not get set entirely, only a sub-object, and since that sub-object does not have the stop function, it gives an error

> oldCollector.stop is not a function

Is there a way to fix this, and why does this happen?

Example: This is a collector:

```
InteractionCollector {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { end: [Array], collect: [Array] },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    filter: [AsyncFunction: filter],
    options: {
      filter: [AsyncFunction: filter],
      time: 67709,
      interactionType: 3,
      channel: [TextChannel]
    },
    collected: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    ended: false,
    _timeout: Timeout {
      _idleTimeout: 67709,
      _idlePrev: [TimersList],
      _idleNext: [TimersList],
      _idleStart: 21969,
      _onTimeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      _timerArgs: undefined,
      _repeat: null,
      _destroyed: false,
      [Symbol(refed)]: false,
      [Symbol(kHasPrimitive)]: false,
      [Symbol(asyncId)]: 741,
      [Symbol(triggerId)]: 0
    },
    _idletimeout: null,
    handleCollect: [Function: bound handleCollect] AsyncFunction,
    handleDispose: [Function: bound handleDispose] AsyncFunction,
    messageId: null,
    channelId: '988393091528523816',
    guildId: '988393091067174973',
    interactionType: 'MESSAGE_COMPONENT',
    componentType: null,
    users: Collection(0) [Map] {},
    total: 0,
    empty: [Function: bound empty],
    _handleChannelDeletion: [Function: bound _handleChannelDeletion],
    _handleThreadDeletion: [Function: bound _handleThreadDeletion],
    _handleGuildDeletion: [Function: bound _handleGuildDeletion],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
}
```

and if I set it with quick.db via `db.set(interaction.user.id, collector)`, it returns this and crashes:

```
{
      collected: [],
      messageId: null,
      channelId: '988393091528523816',
      guildId: '988393091067174973',
      interactionType: 'MESSAGE_COMPONENT',
      componentType: null,
      users: [],
      total: 0
}
```

How I set it in the db:

```
 const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
    filter,
    time: utils.rng(50000, 100000),
  });
  collectorMap.set(interaction.user.id, collector);
```

Comment: I would say it's not much of a good idea to set collectors in a database. They're meant to be local. Collectors aren't meant to run forever anyways, and stop working as soon as the process is exited. Maps are probably the best approach here IMO